# Customize code between custom tags in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to create custom tag only for better visual experience.

like in php if we use comment tag,

```
/*
    comment 1
    comment 2
    comment 3
*/
```

it change the color coding.

Similarly I want to create a tag like

```
// log start
    executable code here... 
    but should look like comment or blur
// log end
```

I know this is weird but if there anything in vscode settings or any custom plugin or any extension will be helpful

Comment: look at the Highlight extension

Comment: So you want your lines of code between `//log start` and `//log begin` to be all formatted in a particular color ? Or you just need easy navigation? If it is just for easy navigation then VSCode has plugins for that like [Bookmark](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks) , [Comment Anchors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ExodiusStudios.comment-anchors) , [TODO HIghlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight)

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick I want it in particular color or faded like comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) extension to achieve this. You can set up custom regexes and apply specific styles to code that matches those regexes.

Install the extension, add this as a custom regex:

```js
"(// log start(.|\\n)+?// log end)": {
      "decorations": [
        {
          "overviewRulerColor": "#ffcc00",
          "backgroundColor": "#ffcc00",
          "color": "#1f1f1f",
          "fontWeight": "bold"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Obviously, replace the colors with what you want. This is what it looks like with my settings:
[image]

Comment: Woooo! You saved bounty at last moment! working like a charm.

Comment: I see one problem here, If you use two pair of tags on one page. It will consider it as one tag and highlight everything in between :(

Comment: Just add a `?` as in `(\/\/ log start(.|\n)+?\/\/ log end)`  see https://regex101.com/r/CpNxcN/1

Comment: Yeah, that was a problem with my regex, just add a ? like @Mark said. I'll edit the answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (depending on your colors:

```
"highlight.regexes": {
  "([ \\t]*// log start)([\\S\\s]+?)([ \\t]*// log end)": {
    "decorations": [
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#fff9",
        "color": "#0006",
        "letterSpacing": "4px",
         "after" : {
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "contentText": "\u2003\u2003\u2003\u2003\u2003\u274d",
          "color": "black"
        }
      },
      {
        "color": "#0006",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#fff9",
        "color": "#0006",
        "letterSpacing": "4px",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here the parts are separately captured so you can do different things with them:

[image: Highlight Log Comments]